# PHP version showing different in browser and command line

Tags: php, ubuntu, command-line, version

The PHP version is showing different
php -v showing PHP 7.2.19 while http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php showing 7.1.13, I want 7.2.19, How to solve this issue, Thank you in advance

Comment: https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-switch-between-multiple-php-versions-in-ubuntu/
Have you check this link?

Comment: Yes @VishalTarkar

Answer (score 1):

Hey uninstall all PHP version from your system. and try to install fresh PHP version 7.2.19
it will do it

Answer (score 0):

PHP showing different version on CLI means that Xampp/Wamp is of older version.
You can upgrade them or simply you can uninstall and then re-install PHP again with the desired version.
You might have installed PHP standalone and also have installed Xampp/Wamp together, that`s why there is a mismatch in the PHP version.

Comment: Okay let me check

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed a fresh wamp or xampp then this should not be the case, plz check the path of PHP environmental variable (command line **php -v** pick this path) and check the PHP path on the webpage by using phpinfo() and you will get that there are two PHP versions are running.

Comment: Okay @sachin, i have installed new PHP version