# Composer does not see the right php version

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, version

For context: I created a Laravel 9 application on My windows operator. I have tried literally everything imaginable, ignore platform reqs, reinstall composer, get the newest PHP version, change environment variables, just to name a few. But no success. Every time I run the application (using homestead) I get the same error message:

`Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 8.0.11.`

Now here is the interesting part, upon checking PHP version in the terminal using `php -v` I get the version that I am actually using (rather than what composer is saying: "8.0.11"):

`PHP 8.1.8 Copyright (c) The PHP Group Zend Engine v4.1.8, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies`

Can someone please help me with this issue? I have seriously been trying for more than a few weeks just to fix this. And it's getting on my nerves as it always happens every time I start a new Laravel application.

Comment: what's your composer version

Comment: Check by running this command 

which PHP

and give this path in composer

Comment: The version you see *in the terminal*, and the version running *on the website* are not necessarily the same - you may have more than version of PHP enabled and configured to be used in different places. If you put `echo phpversion();` *in your actual application*, you will see what version it is using; you can also use [phpinfo()](https://php.net/phpinfo) to find out all about how and where it's configured.

Comment: Run This code in terminal composer -V

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP version showing different in browser and command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58655083/php-version-showing-different-in-browser-and-command-line)

Comment: Also, keep in mind that reinstalling Composer won't change the PHP version you are using

Comment: @user19570962 I use the latest version of Composer (as of now that's 2.3.10.)

Comment: @Shibon Okay, I got "/usr/bin/php/", where do I give Composer the set path?

Comment: @IMSoP it appears that my virtual box homestead, Ubuntu Linux is using version 8.0.11. How do I change it?

Comment: @NicoHaase Unfortunately it wasn't the answer I was looking for. I made sure to delete all previous PHP versions and installed the newest one (8.1.8) but no success. It didn't fix the error.

Comment: @EdwinSlotboom I've never used Laravel Homestead personally, but the docs talk about choosing the PHP version here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/homestead#php-versions